# Mac OS X 10.12 Sierra selenium Python

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I'm trying to run Selenium Python scripts using Python 2.7 which came installed on Macbook Air & getting ERR for:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("test-type")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
**driver.get("https://www.google.com/");**
driver.quit()
```

also installed Python 3.5 but running from python3 ERRs unable to find modules:
**ImportError: No module named 'selenium'**

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `pip3 install selenium`?

Comment: tried that:>>> driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

Comment: also tried using python3:

Comment: >>> driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

Answer (score 0):

I finally got back to this & am now able to use both FireFox & Chrome with Selenium 3 on my MacBook Air running macOS Sierra (10.12.1). I used FF 50.1.0, Selenium 3, & Python 2.7.10 or Python 3.5.2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#/usr/local/bin/geckodriver (in PATH)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/Volumes/Untitled/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
browser.quit()
```